# Elixir - Convert List into a Map

Tags: elixir

What would be an elegant, efficient way for converting a list like `[1,2,3,4]` into the map  `%{1=>2, 3=>4}`? I wrote this:

```
     Enum.reduce([1,2,3,4],%{}, fn(item, acc) ->
        case Map.get(acc, :last) do
          nil ->
            Map.put(acc, :last, item)
          last ->
            acc = Map.put(acc, item, last)
            Map.drop(acc, [:last])
        end
      end)
```

But this does not seem very elegant. Is there a more elegant and cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: One important question is: what do you want to happen when there's an odd number of elements in the original list? Drop the last value or assign it a default value of `nil` for example? With all solutions using `Enum.chunk`, you can supply default values via `Enum.chunk(2, 2, [nil])`, whereas a plain `Enum.chunk(2)` will discard chunks that cannot be filled completely.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.chunk_every/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/2):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] 
  |> Enum.chunk_every(2) 
  |> Enum.map(fn [a, b] -> {a, b} end) 
  |> Map.new
```

Answer (score 35):

You can avoid the extra call to `Enum.map/2`, and build the new map directly using [`Map.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/2):

```elixir
[1,2,3,4]
|> Enum.chunk_every(2)
|> Map.new(fn [k, v] -> {k, v} end)
```

---

<sup>**Update:** The previous version of this answer used `chunk/2` but that has been deprecated in favor of `chunk_every/2`.</sup>

Answer (score 13):

Using [`Enum.into`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/3), which takes a transform function as second parameter:

```
list
|> Enum.chunk_every(2)
|> Enum.into(%{}, fn [a, b] -> {a, b} end)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use tail recursion to accomplish this:

```
defmodule Test do
  def f(list, acc \\ [])

  def f([x, y | xs], acc), do: f(xs, [{x, y} | acc])
  def f(_, acc), do: Map.new(acc)
end
```

This solution is more time efficient than the other solutions proposed. I wrote the following module to be able to benchmark the different solutions:

```
defmodule Benchmark do

  # My solution
  def alex(xs, acc \\ [])
  def alex([x, y | xs], acc), do: alex(xs, [{x, y} | acc])
  def alex(_, acc), do: Map.new(acc)

  # nietaki's solution
  def nietaki(xs) do
    xs
    |> Enum.chunk_every(2, 2, :discard)
    |> Enum.map(fn [x, y] -> {x, y} end)
    |> Map.new()
  end

  # Sheharyar's solution
  def sheharyar(xs) do
    xs
    |> Enum.chunk_every(2, 2, :discard)
    |> Map.new(fn [x, y] -> {x, y} end)
  end

  # Patrick's solution
  def patrick(xs) do
    xs
    |> Enum.chunk_every(2, 2,:discard)
    |> Enum.into(%{}, fn [x, y] -> {x, y} end)
  end

  # Your solution
  def chip(xs) do
    Enum.reduce(xs, %{}, fn(item, acc) ->
      case Map.get(acc, :last) do
        nil ->
          Map.put(acc, :last, item)
        last ->
          acc = Map.put(acc, item, last)
          Map.drop(acc, [:last])
      end
    end)
  end

  # Function to do the time benchmarks.
  def timed(f, list, times \\ 10) do
    tests =
      for _ <- 0..times do
        :timer.tc(fn -> apply(__MODULE__, f, [list]) end) |> elem(0)
      end
    avg = Enum.sum(tests) / times
    {f, avg}
  end

  # Test function.
  def test(list, times \\ 10) do
    list = Enum.to_list(list)
    [:alex, :chip, :patrick, :nietaki, :sheharyar]
    |> Stream.map(fn f -> timed(f, list, times) end)
    |> Enum.sort(fn {_, x}, {_, y} -> x < y end)
  end
end
```

So the bechmark for small lists is the following:

```
iex(1)> Benchmark.test(0..100)
[alex: 10.1, sheharyar: 27.7, nietaki: 27.8, patrick: 29.2, chip: 63.5]
```

And for large lists the following:

```
iex(2)> Benchmark.test(0..1_000_000)
[
  alex: 197784.6,
  patrick: 369645.9,
  nietaki: 370870.2,
  sheharyar: 372616.4,
  chip: 794839.6
]
```

The results are the average run time in microseconds and less is better. As you can see, good ol' tail recursion (`Benchmark.alex/1`) does a better job in this case.

I hope this help :)

Comment: Interesting answer. It's a shame that as the code gets more idiomatic, it gets slower :-(

Comment: On Elixir 1.7.1 Patrick's solution is even slower (but only the first time running): `[alex: 0.5, chip: 0.8, sheharyar: 2.7, nietaki: 3.2, patrick: 232.6]`. It also seems to intermittently perform better than one or two of the others on subsequent runs. I guess it's something to do with how the transform function to `Enum.into/3` is evaluated.