# How to transform this list into a map?

Tags: elixir

I have a list of tuples:

```elixir
[
  {'key1', %{ 'a' => 9543243,
              'b' => 677,
              'c' => 733}},
  {'key2', %{ 'a' => 543,
              'b' => 778,
              'c' => 222}},
  {'key3', %{ ..... }}
]
```

How to transform it into a map?

```elixir
%{
  'key1' => %{ 'a' => 9543243,
               'b' => 677,
               'c' => 733 },
  'key2' => %{ 'a' => 543,
               'b' => 778,
               'c' => 222 },
  'key3' => %{ ..... }
}
```

If I do this via `Enum.map/2`, it’ll create a new **list** yet again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elixir - Convert List into a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262115/elixir-convert-list-into-a-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Enum.into/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#into/2)

```elixir
iex(1)> [{"key1", %{"a" => "b"}}, {"key_2", %{"c" => "d"}}] |> Enum.into(%{})
%{"key1" => %{"a" => "b"}, "key_2" => %{"c" => "d"}}
```

Comment: [Map.new/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Map.html#new/1) is another option